# Create product labels on product images in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

Here, you can see "quality', best" Product labels on product images.

how to create new Product label "DEAL".

I used this "http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-labels-6.html"

but After using this extension, i am got following problem.

1)Product image on product-view page will disappear like as following link :

Is there any other free extension or solution to create Product labels.

please help me to find solution.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your reply. you helped me a lot. before  i asked to change from "sale to quality" , now i want to create new product label "Deal". please help me to find solution.

Comment: hi @Marius please remove "This question may already have an answer here" . thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The question is (at least partially) a duplicate because you have to edit the image sprite. As this is a third party extension please try to first contact the extension developer. He is the person who most likely can and should help you.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply I contacted devoloper. I did't got any reply from devoloper. So i need any other solution, other than that extension.